# Word 2016 on PC - margin transition between pages

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

How do I create a document where the first page has a margin settings that is different to all other pages.

The difficult part here is that the solution MUST respect the margins of the 2nd page as words typed on the 1st page spills over onto the 2nd page.

All the solutions that I have encountered, changes the margins on the second page to conform to the first page margins if you initiate your typing from 1st page and continue typing as the text spill over into the 2nd page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find a detailed discussion of the problem in the article
[Different Margins on First Page](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/DifferentMargins.htm).

The solution has two parts :

- For different margins on top and button, increase the size of the header
  or footer, after setting "Different First Page" on the
  *Header & Footer Tools | Design* tab that appears when you open the header or footer.

  [image]
- Create *apparent* left or right margins by inserting empty text objects.
  Set in the Format tab their "Wrap Text" property to "Square"
  (the text flows around the image),
  then position them to right or left and set their width and height.
  I haven't tried, but this might also be a solution for the top and bottom
  margins.

Comment: Excellent ... this is the solution that I was looking for.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Set default margin for all page from "Layout" and move the nob (indicated on pic) to desire position on first page or on your desire page.

[Please see the image clicking this link [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNhQE.jpg)
(I was changing the margin for second page while a narrow margin applied for all pages.)

Comment: Thanks, but this approach doesn't solve the problem of text added on the first page spilling over to the 2nd page, changing the margin on the 2nd page.